# VBS to run Multiple Macros

Tags: vbscript, excel-2010

I am using this VBS to run a macro on an excel document that has several macros in it. Is there a way to run more than one macro on a single VBS or will I have to create several?

This is the code I am using.

```
strPath = "C:\Users\michael\Desktop\sced.xlsm" 
strMacro = "Macro3" 
Set objApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
objApp.Visible = True
Set wbToRun = objApp.Workbooks.Open(strPath) 
objApp.Run strMacro
wbToRun.Save 
wbToRun.Close 
objApp.Quit
```

I was thinking that I would just be able to list the macros;

```
strMacro = "Macro3"
strMacro = "Macro4"
```

but it only runs the last macro on the list.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest solution for your needs is this:

```
strMacro1 = "Macro3"
strMacro2 = "Macro4"

strPath = "C:\Users\michael\Desktop\sced.xlsm" 
Set objApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
objApp.Visible = True
Set wbToRun = objApp.Workbooks.Open(strPath) 
objApp.Run strMacro1
objApp.Run strMacro2
wbToRun.Save 
wbToRun.Close 
objApp.Quit
```